# Rails 5.1 - text appearing on form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm building out a form on a Rails app and for one of the sections I'm getting some random text in the text field (School Group) and I'm not sure why - 
[image: School group - text in field]

This is the code for the form, am I using the wrong type of field?

```
<% provide :title, "Add Staff Member" %>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <%= f.label :firstname, 'First Name', class: 'col-sm-2' %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.text_field :firstname, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <%= f.label :nickname, 'Nickname', class: 'col-sm-2' %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.text_field :nickname, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <%= f.label :surname, 'Last Name', class: 'col-sm-2' %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.text_field :surname, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <%= f.label :email, 'Email Address', class: 'col-sm-2' %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <%= f.label :email, 'Send Welcome Email?', class: 'col-sm-2' %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= check_box_tag :send_welcome_email %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <%= f.label :user_groups, 'School Group', class: 'col-sm-2' %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.text_field :user_groups, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <%= f.label :timezone, 'Timezone', class: 'col-sm-2' %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.time_zone_select(:timezone, nil, {default: @user.timezone}, {class: 'form-control custom-select'}) %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <h2>Create Password</h2>

  <p><small>Password must be at least six characters long</small></p>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <%= f.label :password, 'New Password', class: 'col-sm-2' %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, 'Confirm Password', class: 'col-sm-2' %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The field for school groups can actually be left blank for the benefit of this form but I want the field there. How do I get rid of this text?

Comment: `user_groups` seems to be an association of type `has_many`. You have used a `text_field` to represent it in your form, thus it will call the `to_s` method of the association and it returns what you are seeing in your field. Either turn the field into a multiple select that lists the available `user_groups` or think of using nested forms for more complex scenarios.

Comment: @Enrai Yes, I've just checked and user_groups is actually a separate table and not an attribute of the User table. Hmm, I have current_school_id as an attribute - this may work better but I need to check this over.

Comment: @Enrai How do I set this field to accept blank completions?

Comment: could you add the `User` model or at least the association declaration?

Comment: @Enrai I think as long as I leave a blank option it will be fine - where do I put this on the form?

Comment: You can also try something like this: `<%= f.select :user_groups, UserGroup.collect { |ug| [ ug.name, ug.id ] },  { include_blank: true }, { multiple: true } %>`

Answer (score 2):

it's not some random text it might be a association in your `User` or `@user` probably column name is named same as the association name or may be a typeo.